# Is there an easy way to repeatedly connect a Magic Trackpad to different workstations?

Tags: macos, bluetooth, magic-trackpad

We pair program where I work, and like many people there, I have my own mouse and keyboard that I take with me as I rotate between workstations.  I want to try using a magic trackpad  at work, but I distinctly recall a coworker having a lot of trouble getting the trackpad to pair every time he rotated stations; eventually he just put a trackpad at every workstation of our team's.

If I wanted to reconnect a single trackpad to a different iMac at least once every day, what would be the easiest way to do it?  I'm still pretty new to OSX so I'm not sure where to begin researching this.